# Is Cyclops’ mutant power just an organic version of Iron Man's repulsor tech?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, iron-man

They occupy the same universe so we have to assume the same physics apply. Iron Man's repulsor tech is described as an inertia-less one-way kinetic blast. At higher energy levels, it can can even disintegrate matter in front of it. Cyclops’ eye beams are described exactly the same way. Is there any place in comics or the animation where the two beams are shown to have different powers?

Comment: It's never shown what biological anomaly causes Scotts eyes to shoot an "optic blast". All we know is that he uses a Ruby-Quarts lens. Iron man does not appear to use any Ruby in his lensing.

Comment: @GorchestopherH we know the biological anomaly, it's called the X-gene. At least that's what I thought, I will admit that X-men has always been a hard book for me to get into.

Comment: The "X-Gene" is not a traditional gene, it is a DNA change or anomaly. Regardless, even if you say "a gene is responsible" for his optic blast, it doesn't  mean the gene is creating it, it is responsible for the faculties that manifest it. Iron Man certainly can't embed some genes into his suit and expect it to shoot optic blasts. You can't fly using a blueprint for a jetpack, you need to make the jetpack.

Comment: They don't have the same special effects so they're probably not the same. Even though energy projecting superheroes are one of the main types so it's not unusual to expect that they're each unique.

Comment: Cyclops does not use the ruby quartz to fire his optic blasts. The ruby quartz is to *PREVENT* the optic blasts from firing.

Comment: Well it's a fact that Cyclop's optic blasts have no heat, just force.  Do the Repulsor's generate heat?

Comment: @phantom42 Of course. What I'm saying is: The ruby-quartz lens is the only known non-biological faculty interfacing with the beam. Iron Man does not employ this faculty. Regardless of its function, Iron Man is not using the only non-biological link in the chain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### No, Iron Man's repulsor technology and Cyclops' optically-directed ruby beam (called his optic blast) are not the same effect even though there are potential similarities in the types of damage they may both produce.

**Iron Man's repulsor is a particle beam.**

- Iron Man repulsor technology is a particle beam weapon with explosive and concussive effects. These effects include knockback, explosions and burn effects. The repulsor has been used as a navigational aid, directing Iron Man during flight operations. The technology evidently creates more energy than it uses since Stark plans to use it and the arc reactor energy technology to generate fossil free energy.
- The repulsor technology has also been used as a weapon, able to damage, concuss or destroy matter in its path. Repulsors have an electromagnetic signature and actively interact with matter in a physical process. Some descriptions describe a neutron interaction, others describe a more plasma-driven effect.
- Since Stark Industries has been destroyed in the recent Iron Man Disassembled storyline, he is starting a new enterprise, Stark Resilient, which promises a business model focused on fostering international cooperation and ushering in an era of world peace. How does he arrive at this goal? Simple. By providing the world with an alternative energy source, his patented repulsor technology, Tony hopes to one eliminate Earth's dependence on fossil fuels.

[image: Tony Stark about to try and release repulsor technology to the world as a fossil free energy source.]

*Tony Stark about to try and release repulsor technology to the world as a fossil free energy source.*

**The mutant Cyclops' energy beam is an extra-dimensional kinetic force beam with concussive effects.**

- Cyclops' optic blast does not function in any way similar to repulsor technology with one exception: the optic blast can smash and compress matter in a fashion using concussion effects that resemble an explosion in terms of the type of damage dealt to the target.
- The optic blast does not have a radiation signature. Nor does it emit infrared radiation or heat of any kind. It's only concession to resembling radiation as we know it, is that it travels at the speed of light and appears to be a beam of powerfully bright, red light. (referenced from a cross-over between the Fantastic Four and the Xmen).
- Cyclops also has an extreme range of precision and control rarely seen with repulsors. Cyclops can spread the beam widely, blanketing an area 90 degrees in front of him. He can also tighten the beam and make it precise enough to snuff a candle without damaging anything else in the room.
- The optic blast, while emitted from the eyes of Cyclops does not originate from him, nor is it "energy" in the classic sense. His eyes act as a portal to a dimension filled with the ruby "energy" and Cyclops acts as a release valve into our universe with devastating results.
- The optic blast has a curious ability not possessed by repulsors. Cyclops can use the beam to carom off of various surfaces striking more than one target with the same beam. His ability is augmented with Cyclops curious sense of spatial awareness allowing him to do this using surfaces which should normally not have this potential.

[image: Cyclops ricochets his optic blast destroying multiple targets.]

*Cyclops ricochets his optic blast destroying multiple targets.*

**That these two powers have similar effects has less to do with the source and more to do with the depiction of the effects of the damage. To the average viewer, the concussive force of a repulsor and the knockback ability of Cyclops' optic beam would seem very similar despite their completely different physical origins.**

Comment: So neither blast produces burns or radiation damage (as would be caused by high energy particles and ionizing radiation)? Does that mean all damage is done through kinetic energy or is it some sort of unknown psionic effect? Also, does he use his visor to focus/diffuse/modulate the beam or is this an innate ability his eyes possess?

Comment: Stark's weapon DOES produce particle and radiation damage. Cyclops' optic blast does not. The damage done is purely kinetic in nature. The visor is necessary to control all aspects of the beam's intensity, width, and longevity. Due to the damage his brain has suffered, he cannot control any aspect of the optic beam without his visor. As far as its been shown without his visor its all or nothing.

Comment: As posted above , his eyes act as a portal to a dimension filled with the ruby energy , does cyclops ever think that the energy will ever run out ? has he measured it like someone checking for oil in the ground??!

Comment: No. We are never privy to him trying to figure out how much energy is there. As far as he could tell, there is no effective limit. There have been occasions where he has tried to see how long he could use his powers. He fatigued and never noticed a reduction in output.